# For a system of ODEs $x^\prime (t) = Ax(t)$ with a constant $A$ matrix, does it always has a unique fixed point at the origin?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

- **If proof directly,** I feel like this is related to the uniqueness theorem?

Suppose $x(t) = (x_1,x_2)$, write out the equation of $\frac{dx_1}{dt}$ & $\frac{dx_2}{dt}$. Letting this two equations and their derivatives continuous. Is these all I have to show?

- Or can anyone find a **counter example** to show the statement is wrong?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: @Moo Yep I think that is the question asking for

Comment: If A is the zero matrix, every point is a fixed point.

Comment: @Moo No. The problem just says that for any ODE x'(t) = Ax(t) with a constant A, whether it always has a unique fixed point at origin....

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you! I think this is a good counter example!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of fixed points of the system $\mathbf{x}'(t)=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}(t)$ is given by the kernel $\mathrm{Ker}(\mathbf{A})$ of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$, i.e. the set of vectors $\mathbf{v}$ for which $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$.

We have that $\mathrm{Ker}(\mathbf{A}) = \{\mathbf{0}\}$ if and only if $\mathbf{A}$ is of full rank, i.e. (since it is a square matrix) if and only if $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible. Thus, the origin is the unique fixed point of the system if and only if $\mathbf{A}$ is of full rank, i.e. if and only if $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense!

Comment: What an elegant combination of ODEs and linear algebra